# Insert a different value in underlying table when a view is updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, view

Consider the following example where I have a table and corresponding view:

```
Table           | View
T_EmailAddress  | V_EmailAddress
----------------+----------------
ID      INT     | ID
Status  VARCHAR | Status
Valid   INT     |
Column1 VARCHAR | Column1
ColumnN VARCHAR | ColumnN
```

I have a program that issues the following queries:

```
UPDATE V_EmailAddress SET Status = 'valid'   WHERE ID = 1;
UPDATE V_EmailAddress SET Status = 'invalid' WHERE ID = 2;
```

Is it possible to update the underlying table so that the ***Status*** `valid` and `invalid` is stored as `1` and `0` inside ***Valid*** column of the underlying table.

Note that I cannot change the table or the query. However I can add "normal" columns to the table.

Comment: r u looking for an additional UPDATE query, to convert valid to 1 and invalid to 0?

Comment: can you provide your view definition?

Comment: @Tanner the view is just a subset of columns from the main table but it has a WHERE clause.

Comment: so status is an alias for valid?

Comment: Why not just use an instead of update trigger on the view?

Comment: @ZoharPeled never used it. If that will do the job then you could post that as an answer.

Comment: @Tanner yes but I need 1-0 instead of valid-invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an instead of update trigger on the view.
When ever an update statement on the view will be completed, the trigger will fire. Note that instead of trigger means that the update will be blocked, and you will have to write the update statement to the underling table yourself.

Something along these lines should do the trick:

```
CREATE TRIGGER V_EmailAddress_IO_Update ON V_EmailAddress
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE t
SET Column1 = i.Column1,
    ColumnN = i.ColumnN,
    Valid = CASE WHEN i.[Status] = 'valid' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

FROM inserted i 
INNER JOIN T_EmailAddress t ON i.ID = t.ID

END
```

Note that you must include all the columns that can be updated in the view in your update statement, otherwise they will not be updated.

Comment: Do I need to include the id column in view?

Comment: You already included it in the question... but yes, the view must contain a row identifier (doesn't have to be a single column, anything with a unique index will suffice)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `UPDATE TRIGGER`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_Valid ON T_EmailAddress
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE t
    SET ID = i.ID
        ,Valid = CASE WHEN i.Status = 'Valid' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ,Status = i.Status
        ,Column1 = i.Column1
        ,ColumnN = i.ColumnN
    FROM T_EmailAddress t
        INNER JOIN ON INSERTED i
            ON t.ID = i.ID

END
GO
```

Alternatively, you may want to replace the `Valid` column with a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE T_EmailAddress
DROP COLUMN Valid

ALTER TABLE T_EmailAddress
ADD Valid AS (CASE WHEN Status = 'Valid' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) PERSISTED
```